# iot device identity validation differences between nonce challenge and x.509?

Tags: iot, x509, nonce

From a security perspective, what are the differences between validating an identity of an iot device with a nonce challenge versus an x.509 certificate?

A TPM is available on the client side as a basis for determining identity.

On this page the process is explained using the nonce challenge (created by the server).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-tpm-attestation#validate-the-nonce-and-receive-credentials

Furthermore, there is a link to a page for the x.509 implementation, which unfortunately is not that meaningful and does not explain the differences with regard to security aspects.